# How to cancel alarm in android?

Tags: android, alarm, cancel-button

I'm working on an app where I create events and set alarm for the events. I need to know how to cancel alarm. I'm having trouble with it. Anyone can help me please, thanks.

**UPDATE**

Posted the code, see the code below. AlarmClass.java

```
Button buttonCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClass.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmClass.this, 1, i, 0);



                AlarmManager aManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                aManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm has been cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply cancel an Alarm By `cancel()` method of AlarmManager.

```
AlarmManager am; 
.
.
.
am.cancel ( PendingIntent operation );
```

for e.g.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceive.class);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManager.cancel(sender);
```

You need to pass the `PendingIntent`'s object into cancel() method.

Comment: I've already coded that in my application but did not work. I'll post my codes and see if there is anything wrong or anything missing in my codes.

Comment: what ?? you have started the alarm and cancel it in the next time ? what is the purpose of the Alarm then ?

Comment: i just want to test if i cancel the alarm that i've set for the events that user creates

Comment: but , why you are cancelling it in the next line only ? cancel it on anther button's click something.

Comment: i got another button to set the alarm. This button is to cancel the alarm that is being set. But our codes are the same. So my question is how to cancel the alarm.

Comment: what you code, is already sufficient for canceling an Alarm, i suggest you to make static variable of AlarmManager, it may be possible, you are creating one object of AlarmManager and cancelling the other one.

Answer (score 0):

To stop a service you can use `stopSelf();`

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note, which is kind of silly, is that the AlarmManager will actually send the PendingIntent upon calling cancel().  Why it does this, I have no idea.  Not sure if you're noticing this, but I am.  To fix this I called cancel() on the PendingIntent itself:

```
   myntent = new Intent(SetActivity.this,AlarmActivity.class);
   pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(CellManage_AddShowActivity.this,
             id, myntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   pendingIntent.cancel();
   alarmanager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```